# i'm not able to get FirebaseUser Method...! alredy add packege Firebse Auth

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
```

[image]

Comment: plz check above image to help me out

Comment: check the latest FlutterFire documentation.. they change "FirebaseUser" to "User", The FirebaseUser class has been renamed to User... https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration

Comment: What does "I'm not able to get FirebaseUser Method" mean? We need _exact_ error messages, please, ideally with full tracebacks. Please read [ask].